# ios 8/swift tab bar multi click icon small how i do ?

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

[image]

here tab item icon is multi click after small size changed ...
i want icon not changed ...
storyboard and code in how do i disabled ?

href : [iOS 7.1 issue - Tabbar icon image is automatically resize when touch and drag on that tab button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368524/ios-7-1-issue-tabbar-icon-image-is-automatically-resize-when-touch-and-drag-on)

Comment: what you want to do ? disable multi click ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the bar item from storyboard and keep its image inset like this.
Don't do this in code also. If you have to adjust image position then edit the image

[image]